# How to Make a RasterBrick from HDF5 Files? R

Tags: r, maps, time-series, raster, hdf5

How can one make a `Rasterbrick` in `R` from several `hdf5` files? Often, data are provided in `hdf5` format and one has to convert it to a more friendly format for easy handling.

At the moment I know of the `rhdf5 package` but how to get a `RasterBrick` is that which I am unsure about.

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("rhdf5")
library("rhdf5")
library("raster")
```

You can access several hdf5 files on this link [http://mirador.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/mirador/cart.pl?C1=GPM_3IMERGHH&CGISESSID=fb3b45e091f081aba8823f3e3f85a7d9&LBT_THRESHOLD=4000000](http://mirador.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/mirador/cart.pl?C1=GPM_3IMERGHH&CGISESSID=fb3b45e091f081aba8823f3e3f85a7d9&LBT_THRESHOLD=40000000&MAXFILES=30000&MyNumResults=4&SearchButton=Search%20GES-DISC&beginNum=1&boxsize=0&createlocbox=1&dir=&endNum=4&endTime=2016-02-10%2023%3A59%3A59&event=&filtered=1&keyword=imerg&maxnumber=10&mode=OPS&newStartTime=&newtime=&noShowMorePages=1&ntime=&order=&order1=&order2=&pointLocation=%28-90%2C-180%29%2C%2890%2C180%29&search=1&searchType=Location&searchtime=1&skipped=&startTime=2014-03-01&granulePresentation=groupByTime&trigger=1&totalItems=27264).

You can use two files for illustration.

Thanks!

AT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is using `gdalUtils` to convert the `hdf5` files into `GTiff`. Once you did that you can read them in a stack. Here is an example code:

```
# list all the `hdf5` files 
files <- list.files(path=".", pattern=paste(".*.h5",sep=""), all.files=FALSE, full.names=TRUE)
#choose the band that you want using the sds[] option and write GTiff files.
  for (i in (files)) {
  sds <- get_subdatasets(i)
  r2 <- gdal_translate(sds[1], dst_dataset =paste(i,".tif",sep=""))}
```

Comment: great answer. I already used MATLAB to process the files but your solution works effectively as well. Thanks.